# How can we export the formatted code in Android Studio to be able to read it from anywhere?

Tags: android, android-studio

I would like to do it so I can simply read it on my phone and take notice of mistakes while I'm on the go to correct them later when I get back to my computer. Is there an easy way to do this (or should I settle to use dozens of screenshots) ?

Comment: Probably not that much easier than screenshots, but can't you grab the .java files from your project folder?

Comment: You should download AIDE from the Play Store. Let's you write code, even compile it and test it right on your phone. Git integration.